# Convert a python lambda to either scala or java. Is this possible using py4j?

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark, lambda

I currently am creating a python api for an apache spark framework and would like to use the underlying java or scala code I already have written to drive most of my python. The issue is that I need python lambda expressions that can be converted to java or scala so that they can be re-used within my existing framework. Is there any way to do this using py4j?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like to happen assuming it worked?

Comment: Please [edit] your question

Comment: for instance: I have a scala/java class that takes in a lambda as one of its parameters, lets say its some filter function f (T => Boolean). I want to pass a python lambda instead of a scala/java lambda, but have the python lambda converted to scala/java so I can use my existing logic in my scala/java class. Essentially the same thing as if i was going to convert a java lambda into a scala lambda (x => myJavaFilter.apply(x)) except with python being the lambda expression

Answer (score 2):

Py4J supports implementing Java interfaces from Python - see [here](https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html#implementing-java-interfaces-from-python-callback).

So you need to create Python classes that implement the interfaces in `java.util.function`. For example:

```
class Function:
    def __init__(self, gateway, lambda_function):
        self.gateway = gateway
        self.lambda_function = lambda_function

    def apply(self, arg):
        return self.lambda_function(arg)

    class Java:
        implements = ["java.util.function.Function"]
```

As an example of how to use it - suppose you have a Java method that takes a `Function<Integer, String>`:

```
public class PythonLambdasExample {  
    public static String callFunction(Function<Integer, String> function) {
        return function.apply(42);
    }
}
```

You can invoke it from Python like this:

```
>>> l = lambda i : "The number was %d" % i
>>> function = Function(gateway, l)
>>> result = gateway.jvm.PythonLambdasExample.callFunction(function)
>>> print(result)
The number was 42
```

Comment: Thanks ! worked for me in databricks
for pyspark one can use :
    gateway = sc._gateway

Comment: I'm glad I could help - 3 years after I posted the message!